# bash or shell script - pcap files to csv files conversion

Tags: bash, shell, csv, ubuntu, pcap

i have a folder that contains thousands of .pcap files, and i want to convert those files into .csv (E.g.:1.pcap --> 1.csv, 2.pcap-->2.csv, ...).

I wrote this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in /home/pc/Desktop/pcapfiles/*.pcap; do
tshark -r ./"$f" -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e ip.proto -e frame.len -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f> ./"${f%.pcap}.csv"

done
```

P.S: i tried to do this task with batch script (i already posted the question, but it didn't work with me, so i decided to try with bash script or shell script. I will be very thankful for your help.

Comment: `f in /home/pc/Desktop/pcapfiles/*.pcap` then `./"$f"`. `f` already is `/home/pc/Desktop/pcapfiles/....` so remove the `./` in front of it (unless you want `.//home/pc/Desktop/pcapfiles/....pcap`). The `occurrence=f>` is a bit misleading, suggest `occurrence=f >` a space between `>` and the rest of the string.

Comment: Also remove the `./` before `"${f%.pcap}.csv"`.

Comment: Thank u so much KamilCuk and Barmar for answering me, but while executing the script, an error appears: 
tshark: The file "/home/pc/Desktop/pcapfiles/*.pcap" doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should strip last 5 chars to remove `.pcap` extension and add csv

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in /home/pc/Desktop/pcapfiles/*.pcap; do
    tshark -r ./"$f" -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e ip.proto -e frame.len -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -E occurrence=f > ./"{$f::-5}".csv"
done
```

Comment: This will write to the source directory, not the current directory. The removal of double quotes around the variable is a bug.

Comment: here filenames don't have spaces.but that's not the point here.he is using wrong syntax ${f%.pcap}

Comment: It's not wrong at all; it's a bog-standard POSIX parameter substitution. The syntax in this answer is slightly wrong though (you want `${f` not `{$f` and the minus is also wrong).

Comment: That will strip the last 5 chars its not wrong . You can test it

Comment: I have; that's how I noticed the typos.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your script is that you are looping over a list of files with a full absolute path, and then trying to write to the same path as a sequence of subdirectories of your current directory.

You will want to remove the path from each file name.  You can do that with `basename` or with a parameter substitution, somewhat similarly to how you are already trimming the `.csv` extension.

Even then you cannot use `./"$f"` to refer to `"$f"` becase that would mean `/path/to/current/directory/home/pc/Desktop/pcapfiles/first.pcap` etc.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in /home/pc/Desktop/pcapfiles/*.pcap; do
    base=${f##*/}
    tshark -r "$f" \
        -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time \
        -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e ip.proto -e frame.len \
        -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d \
        -E occurrence=f> ./"${base%.pcap}.csv"
done
```